# Which File Should be used to originate in asterisk to avoid the transcoding for g729 and ulaw codec ? I wants to minimize the CPU load

Tags: asterisk, sip, codec

How can we minimize the server load by using the right codecs and right file played on dialer? Does it matter what file format we are using in voice broadcasting to avoid the trancoding ?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the source codec, 
If your audio is coming in G.729 and PCMU (μ-law) you can have both file formats of the recording you wish to playback in the sounds directory to avoid transcoding them.

If you then get a call on G.722 the audio files will still be transcoded for that call.

[SoX is the self proclaimed Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), it's free and open source and can convert common audio formats to G.729 and PCMU.